# How do I get the row number of matrix if the first two elements are 0 and 1 in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

if I have a matrix:

```
           A = [[0,1,2], [0,2,3], [1,5,6]]
```

I want to find the rows that the first two elements are 0 and 1, get the result

```
           0
```

find the rows that the first elements are 0, get the result

```
           [0,1]
```

How should I do? What is the fastest way?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
>>> A = [[0,1,2], [0,2,3], [1,5,6]]
>>> [i for i, row in enumerate(A) if row[:2] == [0, 1]]
[0]
>>> [i for i, row in enumerate(A) if row[0] == 0]
[0, 1]
```

If you want to create both results at the same time, use a regular loop as the above would iterate your matrix twice:

```
res_0, res_01 = list(), list()
for i, row in enumerate(A):
    if row[0] == 0:
        res_0.append(i)
        if row[1] == 1:
            res_01.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is tagged as [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy), I'm going to assume that `A` is a numpy array rather than a set of nested lists as you've shown it.

In that case you can use a combination of [slice indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing), [vectorized logical comparisons](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html#numpy.equal), [`np.all`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html#numpy.all), and [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0,1,2], [0,2,3], [1,5,6]])

print(np.where(np.all(A[:, :2] == np.array([0, 1]), axis=1))[0])
# [0]
```

To break that down a bit:

```
# index all of the rows and the first two columns of A
print(A[:, :2])
# [[0 1]
#  [0 2]
#  [1 5]]

# for each row, is the first column equal to 0, and is the second equal to 1?
print(A[:, :2] == np.array([0, 1]))
# [[ True  True]
#  [ True False]
#  [False False]]

# do the elements in *both* columns match [0, 1]?
print(np.all(A[:, :2] == np.array([0, 1]), axis=1))
# [ True False False]

# get the indices of the rows for which the above statement is true
print(np.where(np.all(A[:, :2] == np.array([0, 1]), axis=1))[0])
# [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by schore seems good, but since you asked for a fast way, and for loops get quite slow for large arrays I assumed you were using numpy since your question is tagged with it, I had a try at fancy indexing.

```
A = np.array([[0,1,2], [0,2,3], [1,5,6]])

indices = np.array(range(len(A)))

check01 = A[:,:2] ==[0,1]
result01 = (check01)[:,0] * (check01)[:,1]
print(indices[result01])

result0 = (A == 0)[:,0]
print(indices[result0])
```

this gives me

```
[0]
[0 1]
```

I am by no means an expert in writing fast code and there may be even nicer ways. Try to print out the things I define on the way to get a better understanding.